# Jenkins build is not marked as failed if there is an error during .sh file execution

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

The Jenkins job contains Execute shell step with the following command:

```
scp file.zip deploy@host.name:/home/deploy/app.zip
```

If 'file.zip' does not exist the build obviously fails.

Then I create shell script file with the same command, say deploy.sh, and change Execute shell command in Jenkins to:

```
./deploy.sh
```

In this case if 'file.zip' does not exist Console Output contains error message, but the build is marked as successful.

What should I do to have build marked as failed in this case as well?

Comment: did you put  #!/bin/sh in the begining of your script ? This might be the problem http://thingsyoudidntknowaboutjenkins.tumblr.com/post/30255425955/why-does-jenkins-think-my-build-succeeded

Comment: the build succeed regardless of hash-bang line for some reason

Answer (score 1):

By default Jenkins take /bin/sh -xe and  -x will print each and every command.And the other option -e, which causes shell to stop running a script immediately when any command exits with non-zero (when any command fails) exit code.

So by adding the #!/bin/sh will allow you to execute with no option.

you have to know which code it is returning after executing `scp file.zip deploy@host.name:/home/deploy/app.zip` using `echo $?`